# woocommerce product category widget disable parent category link

Tags: css, wordpress, woocommerce

I am using the woocommerce product category widget on my sidebar and footer widget area.

I have 2 parent categories. I would like these to be displayed, but not be clickable links.

You can see the page here http://www.terrykirkwood.co.uk/w

Can anyone advise what css to add to stop these links being clickable?

Thanks

Here's the code from the first occurrence:

```
<li class="cat-item cat-item-47 cat-parent"><a href="http://terrykirkwood.co.uk/w/product-category/originals/">Original Paintings</a><ul class="children">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CSS only controls style, so there is no CSS you can use to disable a hyperlink. You could change the CSS to not change cursors, so it doesn't "look" like a link.

```
.cat-parent a { 
    cursor: default;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.cat-parent .children a {
    cursor: pointer;
    text-decoration: underline;
}
```

And then use some jQuery to actually disable the click function:

```
$('.cat-parent').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

If you were bold you could probably also modify the widget to not print an `<a>` link for parents, but I can't check on that right now.

**Edit**

You can either add the script to one of your theme's scripts, load a new external script file or drop the following into your themes' functions.php:

```
function so_add_this_script_footer(){ 

    if( !is_admin() ) { ?>

    <script>
        jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
            $('.cat-parent > a').click(function(e) {
                e.preventDefault();
            });
        });
    </script>

<?php } 

}

add_action('wp_print_footer_scripts', 'so_add_this_script_footer');
```

Comment: Thanks - I've added in the css, but it has not made any difference. Which file would I add the jQuery to please?

Comment: Thanks. adding the code to functions.php has made the links not work, which is good, except, it also made the child links not work. Also the css, has not affected the parent link at all. Thanks for your help so far - I really appreciate it!

Comment: Sorry I didn't realize that `cat-parent` was the class for the list item and not actually the link. I've adjusted my code again to take this into account and have confirmed it. You might want to add more style rules as I think it still changes color on hover (like most links do), but it achieves what you were asking.

Answer (score 0):

All parent classes have a 'cat-parent' class, so you can either add a condition -  'javascript: void(0)' - in widget for anchor tag 'href'. 
Alternatively , you can add the below jquery code,

```
jQuery('.footer-widget').find('.product-categories li.cat-parent').each(function(){ 

  if(jQuery(this).find('ul.children').length == 1){ 

    jQuery(this).find('a').attr('href','javascript: void(0)');
  } 

});
```

This will reset all parent category links that have child categories. Now, If user clicks on parent category, it will not do anything.

This will also make sure, that if parent categories don't have child categories, then it will not be reset.

Comment: Thanks - which file would I add the jQuery to?

Comment: Won't this disable the links for the child categories instead of the parent categories?